# how to arrange divs with css as a grid?

Tags: html, css, layout

I want to present dynamically generated (PHP, XML) questionnaires to the user in the browser like this: [image: layout draft of questionnaire]

**requirements:**
 1. The left column will will always be a number, the middle and the right column may swap position in some questionnaires.
 2. There will be questionnaires with 200 items or so over multiple pages.
 3. The width of the container (rounded corners) is fixed at 800px at this time, BUT
 4. it has to be flexible / fluid in the near future for being displayed on mobile devices like iPad and iPhone

**what I've tried**
I experimented both with a `<table>` based and a `<div>` based layout:

The `<table>` was clean and simple, but with lots of overhead and not very flexible, e.g. if I swapped middle and right column for item #2 only...

The `<div>` based layout was sleeker, I let the containers float, but have to set the `divs` to a fixed width in order to get them align in columns. In a fluid design, I do not know the widths in advance, which will be a mess then...

**questions** to the pros:
 1. `<table>` or `<div>`, regarding my requirements above, what would you prefer?
 2. is there some magic tool to make this nice and easy?
 3. would you rather serve the raw data and let a client-side script (jQuery) do the positioning instead?

Comment: post your div based code

Comment: Why don't you use a framework like Bootstrap, Foundation or Pure?

Comment: It is not what 'we prefer' but what you find easier to maintain. If you find that the div layout was the easiest and more flexible for you then go with that.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa: because I didn't know they existed. Thanks a lot, seems to be exactly what I need!

Comment: @jeff: well, jeff, I wrote "questions to the **pros**, and I expect pros to prefer state-of-the-art solutions :-)

Comment: @michi Don't worry. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a code example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/inmwD

Either use a wrapping div or a list element

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col1">1</div>
      <div class="col2">Content</div>
      <div class="col3"><input type="radio"/></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Elements within columns will have different heights (see draft in my question). How to have "2" be at the same height as its question in the middle col?

Comment: You want all the columns to fill to match the height of the tallest sibling?

Comment: Your image the heights are varied. You'd have to use javascript to get the height of the tallest and then set min-heights to all the siblings in the row.

Answer (score 1):

1. In my opinion `<table>` is for tables `<div>` is for layout.
2. Yes there are some style templates usually named **grid system** or **css grid** take a look at this stack : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76996/what-is-the-best-css-grid-framework
3. I wont arrange elements around with JavaScript unless it can't be done with css or is a special requirement from the marketing guys. The con about this is that you increase the page render time.

Take a look at this fiddle made with a custom 960 grid system that have 6 columns with the width 150px

Fixed width: http://jsfiddle.net/UjXPR/

Fluid width: http://jsfiddle.net/UjXPR/1/

960 gs customizer: http://grids.heroku.com/

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [bootstrap grid system](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem)

Answer (score 0):

> `1.` `<table>` or `<div>`, regarding my requirements above, what would you prefer?

div is specially used for layout of the page and table is specially used for placing tabular data. so in your condition I would choose the table layout for the questionnaire.

> `2.` is there some magic tool to make this nice and easy?

First dream to design how should this row data look then only accomplish for the site.

> `3.` would you rather serve the raw data and let a client-side script (jQuery) do the positioning instead?

This is not good idea but if the clients need so you could do that.

> And one more thing, you are not asking for your problem with SO but asking what we like, this is not good practice for SO users.

Comment: thank you for your insightful comments. I wrote "question to the **pros**", and I expect the pros to like state-of-the-art solutions. So maybe my wording was misleading.